# Why <select>'s value attribute doesn't set <select>'s value property?

Tags: html, html-select, selected

Supposing a select like

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

I can set the selected option changing it's `value` property:

```
document.getElementById('myselect').value = 'b';
```

But I can't do it with `value` attribute, so the following doesn't work:

```
<?php
  $myselectValue = $_GET['myselect'] ?: 'a';
  // Do something with $myselectValue
?>
<select name="myselect" id="myselect" value="<?php echo $myselectValue; ?>">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

and, instead, I must write uglier and less clean server-side code.

I think it makes more sense to choose the selected option with `<select>`'s `value` attribute instead of `<option>`'s `selected` one.

Why did w3c think that `<option value="x" selected>` is better than `<select value="x">`? Maybe is there any advantage I don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no telling what they were thinking, but there are a couple of cases where `value` may not make sense:

- The value is invalid
- With `<select multiple>`

Also keep in mind that the *property* is different from the *attribute*.

Semantically it makes more sense to have the list of available options (through `<option>`) and the `select` attribute indicating the option (or options) that is actually selected rather than having to reconcile this with an attribute value.

Comment: Is there such a thing as property in HTML standard? I can't find in wiki and google didn't give anything on w3.org. Is it this: "Properties are values of nodes (HTML Elements) that you can get or set"?

Comment: If the value is invalid, it could be the same as no `<option>` with `selected` (the first option is selected by default). And I didn't think about `<select multiple>`, but it could be like classes: you can have multiple classes with one attribute. But maybe semantically you are right.

Comment: @user4035: Yes. The term property is used in the Document Object Model (DOM). HTML attributes are exposed as properties on the element object.